# Inputting CSV in QGIS graphical modeler and defining its geometry

Tags: csv, qgis-3, import, qgis-modeler

Is it possible to have a model in QGIS graphical modeller which accepts a CSV with geometry fields and then allows you to use them for the rest of the model as if it was a vector file?

This is required so I can bypass having to import the CSV into QGIS and defining it there before adding it to a model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "VectorLayer" as input and "Create points layer from table" under algorithms:

[image]

This creates point vector that includes z values. 
Use "Select file" button next to drop down list when you use the model:

[image]

Comment: Thanks but the File/Folder input is not accepted as an input to the algorithm

Comment: Yes, sorry. You should use vector layer as input not File/Folder. When you use the model use "Select file" button instead of drop down.